# netbeans is locking files and preventing saving source files

Tags: netbeans-8

when working on a remote project, netbeans frequently creates lock files. I get this error message when I try and save:

cannot write to locked file:

It doesn't state where the lock file is, and I don't see any obvious lock files.

The solution appears to be to abandon the file, and restart netbeans.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This was a known issue with NetBeans 8.0 but was fixed in NetBeans 8.1 (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246127). Which version of NetBeans 8 are you using?